# Large text display in Linux

Tags: linux, display

I'm looking for but can't seem to find a utility do essentially do what 
[this (question on Ask Different SE)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37981/show-text-using-large-type-without-relying-on-third-party-applications) does, but in Linux.

I like to be able to show people something on my screen without having to enlarge the selection by magnifying the screen/window.

When I used Mac, I had a variety of bash aliases and functions for doing just this with Quicksilver, but now my main machine runs on Arch, where I have not found a similar tool. I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to to make a quick Python script for this with some GUI framework, but would rather not duplicate effort if it exists and I simply don't know the right words to search.

I've seen banner, which tries to do similar in the terminal, and tried trawling Google to no avail. Even better would be a utility to display the compiled LaTeX of piped text dynamically scaled based on the amount of text and screen size.

Has anyone seen a utility that does this?

**tl;dr:**

- Environment: Arch/Linux
- Desired input: text (via pipe)
- Desired output: translucent text dynamically sized to fit screen dismissable by hitting a key or changing focus

([Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577679/large-text-display-in-linux))

Comment: I use ``toilet -t 1-800-MY-LINUX`` in [Guake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake) to scale text. It's similar to ``banner`` but has more options, like the ability to choose font face and color, and to specify text width. It doesn't produce an overlay though, so I'm only posting this as a comment. ``figlet -t`` also produces similar results but with a different style

Comment: Possible ideas: conky or dzen2.